# Reading csv files with filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with multiple record types identified by the first character in the first field. How do I read this into a pandas dataframe filtering on records of type 'M'?

Comment: First create DataFrame by  `df = pd.read_csv(file)` and then filter by dupe.

Comment: Thanks, but cannot read the file in total as the file has varying numbers of fields.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Then get me know, I reopen question.

Comment: My csv file is not regular, the different records can contain any number of fields, I don't know if these will fit into a dataframe. In the records below I only need those starting with 'M':-
MA,1,2
MB,2,3
Z1,0,1,2,3,4
Z4,0,1,2
Z8,0,1,3,8,2,9
X2,4
MA,5
MB,6
Z1,0,1,5,3,4,7,9,25
Z4,0,1,4